# Drupal 7 - set input value depending select value

Tags: drupal-7, state, hook-form-alter

I create a hook_form_alter and i want to change the input value depending on a select option.

I catch the name value :

```
global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
$name = $user_fields->field_user_name['und']['0']['value'];
```

Actually i use form states :

```
$form['field_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#default_value' => $name,
    '#weight' => 4,
    '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
            'select[name="who_is_registering"]' => array('value' => REGISTRATION_REGISTRANT_TYPE_ANON),
            '#default_value' => '',
        ),
        'required' => array(
            'select[name="who_is_registering"]' => array('value' => REGISTRATION_REGISTRANT_TYPE_ANON),
        ),                  
    ),
);
```

the goal is to set the name if the select value is different from anon (REGISTRATION_REGISTRANT_TYPE_ANON) and hide the input ... and to show an empty field on the other case.

Comment: use conditonal fields module https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Comment: finally i used 100% jquery on this stuff : collecting the user data and passing them to jquery.